# Why is MEMBER OF() faster than JSON_CONTAINS()?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I'm playing with MySQL 8's new JSON capabilities, in particular multi-value indexes.

I noticed that there are 2 ways to check if a JSON array contains a given value: the [MEMBER OF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of) operator, and the [JSON_CONTAINS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) function.

They both return the same set of results for every query I make, but surprisingly, `MEMBER OF` seems to be 3x faster than `JSON_CONTAINS`.

Example on a table with 200,000 records, with around 700,000 values total in the `catIds` fields:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  catIds JSON NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY test_categories ((CAST(catIds AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)))
);

INSERT INTO test (catIds) VALUES('[123, 456]');
...
```

... some 200,000 inserted records later:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE 51 member of (catIds);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     7287 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(catIds, '51');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     7287 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.36 sec)
```

If first thought that this was because the stringified JSON value `'51'` was maybe converted on each iteration, so I tried assigning it to a variable first; but this does not make it any faster:

```
mysql> SET @value = CAST(51 as JSON);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(catIds, @value);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     7287 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.38 sec)
```

Unless I'm mistaken, `MEMBER OF()` and `JSON_CONTAINS()` are equivalent feature-wise. In this case, **why is one of them faster than the other?**

Comment: _"Unless I'm mistaken, MEMBER OF() and JSON_CONTAINS() are equivalent feature-wise."_ Did you compare their documentation pages to confirm this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I made this statement a bit fast indeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`JSON_CONTAINS()` does more complex work than `MEMBER OF`.

`JSON_CONTAINS()` must parse its second argument, a candidate JSON document that you're searching for within the stored JSON document.

The candidate may not be a simple scalar as you're searching for in your example above. It could be a more complex document with its own nested arrays and objects.

Therefore comparing the candidate to the stored document must potentially compare in a more complex manner, not just searching for a single scalar value, but comparing recursively, all nested elements.

Even if your example search is for a simple scalar value, it still invokes the same code path that *might* need to search for a complex document. Based on your timing measurement, that code path seems to have more overhead.

Whereas `MEMBER OF` only searches for a scalar value, and only searches in an array. It can also optimize by using a cached, pre-sorted array.

See https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/item_json_func.cc#L3852 for the code.

Comment: Note that `NOT MEMBER OF` will not work against empty JSON arrays, it will incorrect ly return no results

Answer (score 0):

The reason is even though it's using the same index, It also matters, how you used that particular index.
There are two types of index usage (given by `type` column or `access_type` in  json format output of `EXPLAIN` command)

There are two classes of index search in my opinion (or Understanding)

1. const type / ref type (directly lookup for a key in B+ tree)
2. range type (find keys in range on index)

when you are using `MEMBER OF` function it uses `ref` type for index search, when you use `JSON_OVERLAPS` it uses `range` type index search (will do >= and <= key set search and then do intersection), which is obviously slow, this can be verified through `EXPLAIN` command output.

Output for `EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE 51 member of (catIds);`, you observe that it's using index called `test_categories`, but using `type` column value is  `ref` (lookup for 51 in secondary index B+tree, then lookup for the corresponding primary keys).
[image]

Where as you can observe the output for `EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(catIds, '51');`, where you can see that `type` column value is `range` (find keys in range [51, 51], do some preprocessing and then lookup for these primary keys on clustered indices, then possible de-duping logic on them)

[image]