# How can I use get a value stored in a json column in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql, json, json-extract

| id | lessons |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["3M-232","3M-313"] |
| 2 | ["3M-311","3M-312"] |
| 3 | ["3M-443","3M-565"] |
| 4 | ["4M-232","4M-313"] |
| 5 | ["4M-311","4M-312"] |
| 6 | ["4M-443","4M-565"] |

How can get rows that match lessons with "3M-232" as one of them

```
SELECT * FROM merged_lesson where lessons = "3M-232";
```

Expected only row 1 to be returned

originally posted as [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au2sp.png)

Comment: and I change "that match lessons with "2M-232""   to  "that match lessons with "3M-232" (to match your SQL statement., see [Proofread before posting!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Proofread%20before%20posting!)

Comment: Sharing data as text, not as image, is preferred, so I copied the text from your image...    ,see: [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages)

Answer (score 4):

We can use [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) function:

```
SELECT id, JSON_PRETTY(lessons) AS lessons
FROM tbl_name
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(lessons, '"3M-232"')
```

Or, as pointed out by @lemon ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538181/why-is-member-of-faster-than-json-contains)), it would be much faster to use `MEMBER OF`:

```
SELECT id, JSON_PRETTY(lessons) AS lessons
FROM tbl_name
WHERE '3M-232' MEMBER OF(lessons)
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cxAtfDeb)

Comment: Check out [`MEMBER OF`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538181/why-is-member-of-faster-than-json-contains) alongside `JSON_CONTAINS`.

Comment: @lemon, Thank you for pointing this out and thank [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) for that invaluable post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `JSON_TABLE` to convert array to rows :

```
select *
from mytable
cross join JSON_TABLE(lessons, '$[*]'
                      COLUMNS (
                           lesson VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$')
                      ) j
where j.lesson = '3M-232';
```

Result :

```
id  lessons                 lesson
1   ["3M-232", "3M-313"]    3M-232
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/drnSQfmS)